# Swift: function compiles, no warning, but can this function even be used?

Tags: swift, swift3, variadic-functions

In Swift it seems to be possible to create a variadic function with a vararg parameter which isn't the last parameter of the function.

I created the following function:

```
func test1(_ array: String..., _ tag: String){
    print("[\(tag)] array: \(array)")
}
```

Because it's possible to define a vararg parameter without making it the last parameter I suspected that the Swift compiler would just take the last argument and make it the argument for the second parameter.

```
test1("Hello", "World", "Greeting")
```

But this doesn't work, which is not too strange.

This doesn't work either:

```
let arrayOfStrings: [String] = ["Hello", "World"]
test1(arrayOfStrings, "Greeting")
```

Obviously giving the second parameter a label works.

```
func test2(_ array: String..., tag: String){
    print("[\(tag)] array: \(array)")
}
```

But I decided to make another try. This function compiles doesn't generate a warning, but can I even use it?

```
func test3(_ array: String..., _ tag: Int){
    print("[\(tag)] array: \(array)")
}

test3("Hello", "World", 1)
```

**Is it possible to call the first method or the third method, without giving the second parameter a label?**

> **Side note:** Is this a language feature? Shouldn't the compiler have warn me? It currently tells me that I'm missing the second parameter when calling the function, but to me it seems that it's not even possible to provide this parameter.

Comment: In the last snippet you changed type of `tag` parameter and calling `test1` instead of `test3`. Can you check if it's what you wanted to put in?

Comment: @user28434 Corrected.

Comment: I assume that this is a "theoretical" question - or do you have a use-case for such a function? You certainly seem to be correct that it is a well formed function declaration that cannot then be called!

Comment: Seems to be a bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-494?jql=text%20~%20%22variadic%22